# Benchmarking C++ virtual functions

Tags: c++, benchmarking, virtual-functions, microbenchmark

I think that every C++ programmer at some point heard the statement "virtual functions are slow". So I decided to benchmark virtual functions against regular member functions.

Unfortunately, I don't have much experience in benchmarking "low-level" C++ code, and don't known how to properly avoid compiler or HW (branch predictor mostly) optimization effects.

The problem that I'm facing right now is that when I run my benchmarks (which I provide below), I almost always get the result that calling both virtual and regular functions have the same speed, and sometimes virtual functions work even faster!

This is how I wrote my benchmark using `google/benchmark` library:

```
static void BM_MemberCall(benchmark::State& state) {
    Base* b = new Derived();

    for ([[maybe_unused]] auto _ : state) {
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(b->Foo());
        benchmark::ClobberMemory();
    }
}
BENCHMARK(BM_MemberCall);

static void BM_VirtualCall(benchmark::State& state) {
    Base* b = new Derived();

    for ([[maybe_unused]] auto _ : state) {
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(b->VirtualFoo());
        benchmark::ClobberMemory();
    }
}
BENCHMARK(BM_VirtualCall);
```

My class definitions are as follows, declared in `util.h`:

```
#pragma once

// generate 10 virtual functions
#define VFOO(NAME, ID, ...) \
    __attribute__((noinline)) virtual int NAME ## ID ## _0() __VA_ARGS__; \
    __attribute__((noinline)) virtual int NAME ## ID ## _1() __VA_ARGS__; \
    __attribute__((noinline)) virtual int NAME ## ID ## _2() __VA_ARGS__; \
    __attribute__((noinline)) virtual int NAME ## ID ## _3() __VA_ARGS__; \
    __attribute__((noinline)) virtual int NAME ## ID ## _4() __VA_ARGS__; \
    __attribute__((noinline)) virtual int NAME ## ID ## _5() __VA_ARGS__; \
    __attribute__((noinline)) virtual int NAME ## ID ## _6() __VA_ARGS__; \
    __attribute__((noinline)) virtual int NAME ## ID ## _7() __VA_ARGS__; \
    __attribute__((noinline)) virtual int NAME ## ID ## _8() __VA_ARGS__; \
    __attribute__((noinline)) virtual int NAME ## ID ## _9() __VA_ARGS__;

// generate 100 virtual functions
#define VFOO100(NAME, ...) \
    VFOO(NAME, 0, __VA_ARGS__) \
    VFOO(NAME, 1, __VA_ARGS__) \
    VFOO(NAME, 2, __VA_ARGS__) \
    VFOO(NAME, 3, __VA_ARGS__) \
    VFOO(NAME, 4, __VA_ARGS__) \
    VFOO(NAME, 5, __VA_ARGS__) \
    VFOO(NAME, 6, __VA_ARGS__) \
    VFOO(NAME, 7, __VA_ARGS__) \
    VFOO(NAME, 8, __VA_ARGS__) \
    VFOO(NAME, 9, __VA_ARGS__)

struct Base {
    int Foo();
    VFOO100(A);
    __attribute__((noinline)) virtual int VirtualFoo();
    VFOO100(Z);
};

struct Derived : public Base {
    VFOO100(A, override);
    __attribute__((noinline)) int VirtualFoo() override;
    VFOO100(Z, override);
};
```

With the help of `VFOO100` I generate 200 virtual functions in order to make virtual table big, and just in case there is some lexicological sorting involved in finding the right method, I generate 100 methods lexicologically lower than `VirtualFoo` and 100 bigger.

All methods definitions are the same (both regular and virtual, defined in separate TU named `util.cpp`):

```
{
    asm("");
    return 0;
}
```

Sample benchmark results:

```
(same)
---------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark               Time             CPU   Iterations
---------------------------------------------------------
BM_MemberCall        1.23 ns         1.23 ns    524344569
BM_VirtualCall       1.23 ns         1.23 ns    564752961

(virtual functions are worse)
---------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark               Time             CPU   Iterations
---------------------------------------------------------
BM_MemberCall        1.22 ns         1.22 ns    522068585
BM_VirtualCall       1.48 ns         1.33 ns    557440234

(virtual functions are faster!)
Benchmark               Time             CPU   Iterations
---------------------------------------------------------
BM_MemberCall        1.33 ns         1.33 ns    475669505
BM_VirtualCall       1.25 ns         1.25 ns    555128195
```

My questions:

1. If virtual functions are indeed slower than regular once, how can I measure it and see for myself? What mistakes did I make in my approach?
2. Why in this tests I sometimes see virtual functions being slower than regular once?

My setup:

```
2024-02-12T17:41:29+03:00
Running ./src/apps/bench/function_calls/calls
Run on (12 X 2600 MHz CPU s)
CPU Caches:
  L1 Data 32 KiB
  L1 Instruction 32 KiB
  L2 Unified 256 KiB (x6)
  L3 Unified 12288 KiB
Load Average: 3.04, 4.39, 4.52
```

Comment: Try to move `b` creation to separate translation unit (e.g., a factory function `Base* makeDerived() {return new Derived();}`), so that compiler doesn't know the dynamic type of `b` and cannot devirtualise calls.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Good point! But tried it, and results are pretty much the same

Comment: In my experience what is really slow about virtual functions is not the virtual function call overhead itself, but the fact that you will (most of the time) have to use dynamic allocations, which is especially noticeable once you have containers of objects. Iterating over an array of pointers and calling virtual functions will involve a lot of cache misses from following said pointers to other memory locations

Comment: @PepeHands Did you try to use a debugger, or inspect the assembly to see what the compiler is actually doing? I'm suspecting that somehow the compiler is still able to inline, even with a separate CU. Maybe some sort of LTO is activated. I've seen compilers also be extra sneaky and record the fact that a function only returns a constant, and remove the call (even if it's marked no-inline).

Comment: @UnholySheep Hmm, interesting, never thought about it this way. But even though I understand what you mean and how it effects performance, still everybody talks about "virtual functions" by themselves being slow. Do people confusing cause and effect here? Is it not virtual functions themselves but this pointer following?

Comment: There are two things that make virtual functions "slow". The obvious one is the dispatch: there's an extra indirection when the function is called. If the function isn't utterly trivial this makes no noticeable difference. The less obvious one is that the compiler generally can't expand the function inline, which can make a big difference for small functions.

Comment: calling a function takes very little time compared to what a typical function does. The only time I noticed a significant difference was when the function did literally nothing. In that case the non virtual one was optimized away completely, while the virtual call was still present. Please try to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Looks like your test code is invalid, since compiler can reason that instance of the object under test, has only one virtual possible implementation to call, so virtual call is not needed and can be reduced to regular call. Simply compiler is able to see that `b` is a pointer to `Base` but it always points to instance of `Derived`, so it can avoid use of virtual call.

Comment: @MarekR Yes, I probably should update my question, but I tried solution from first comment by @Yksisarvinen and added global function `Base* GlobalBase();` which returns `Derived*` and defined in separate TU, and the result are the same

Comment: Side note: Modern compilers can *de-virtualize* functions in many cases - especially for leaf classes where the class is marked `final`.

Answer (score 5):

Virtual functions in C++ have caused slowness in a few ways.

1. They can block inlining.  Vtables are more complex than direct function calls.  With a direct function call, it is trivial to know what code you are invoking; sometimes you need LTO to cross translation units.  With a vtable, innoculous changes can block devirtualization.  This is difficult to profile, because your simple benchmark by definition is simple.

This is similar to function pointers or std functions.

2. They add a memory access over a function pointer.  A function pointer is a one step to code: a virtual call first has to get the vtable, then follow the pointer there.  This extra memory access can be a cache miss and can add to L1 cache pressure.
3. They discourage value types and local storage.  Because vtable based polymorphism doesn't support polymorphic storage out of the box, you end up working with pointers to object data not stored adjacent to each other in cache-friendly ways.
4. They encourage dynamic allocation.  `malloc` is 100s of instructions and `free` is thread-unfriendly.  Most uses of vtables use the heap.  This means that each objects existence has a significant time debt: so often you have overly big objects or lots of wasted time on small ones.
5. They discourage polymophism.  Each distinct type of object has O(vtable size) global overhead: and an object with 1 method tweaked has its own type.  Making millions of combinatorially different types of objects is impractical given how C++ implements virtual dispatch.  So you end up with switch statements in your polymorphic code after a certain point.

Each of these represent a reason I have not used virtual method based dispatch for performance reasons in a shipping commercial application.

Now, in many cases, the lack of performance is relative.  Like, don't use virtual dispatch on a per pixel per frame basis for HD video running at 30 Hz.

Instead, lift the virtual dispatch to the per scanline spot.  All of a sudden this huge overhead is 1000x less important.

But some of these are tricky, in that the costs are not always fully localized (memory and cache pressure, for example).  So thinking about it at a higher level is sometimes needed.

Answer (score 3):

Writing correct performance test for thigh code is very hard and full of subtle traps, from compiler and processor. There are numerous C++ talks from Chandler Carruth showing scale of the problem.

Here is my attempt to write better performance test demo, but I not giving warranty there is no problems with it.

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <tuple>
#include <array>

class Base {
public:
  virtual ~Base() {}

  virtual int foo(int) = 0;
};

class A : public Base {
public:
  int foo(int x) override {
    return bar(x);
  }

  int bar(int x) {
    return x + 1;
  }
};

class B : public Base {
public:
  int foo(int x) override {
    return bar(x);
  }

  int bar(int x) {
    return x - 1;
  }
};

class C : public Base {
public:
  int foo(int x) override {
    return bar(x);
  }

  int bar(int x) {
    return x / 2;
  }
};

class D : public Base {
public:
  int foo(int x) override {
    return bar(x);
  }

  int bar(int x) {
    return 3*x + 1;
  }
};

auto makePointerTuple()
{
  return std::tuple{std::make_unique<A>(), std::make_unique<B>(), std::make_unique<C>(), std::make_unique<D>()};
}

auto makeValuesTuple()
{
  return std::tuple{A(), B(), C(), D()};
}

auto makeArray()
{
  return std::array<std::unique_ptr<Base>, 4>{std::make_unique<A>(), std::make_unique<B>(), std::make_unique<C>(), std::make_unique<D>()};
}

static void TestVirtualCall(benchmark::State& state) {
  auto arr = makeArray();
  int accumulator = 0;
  for (auto _ : state) {
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(arr);
    std::apply([&accumulator](auto&... args) {
        ((accumulator = args->foo(accumulator)), ...);
      }, arr);
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(accumulator);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(TestVirtualCall);

static void TestRegualrCall(benchmark::State& state) {
  auto t = makePointerTuple();
  int accumulator = 0;
  for (auto _ : state) {
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(t);
    std::apply([&accumulator](auto&... args) {
        ((accumulator = args->bar(accumulator)), ...);
      }, t);
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(accumulator);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(TestRegualrCall);


static void TestVirtualFunclWithKnownType(benchmark::State& state) {
  auto t = makePointerTuple();
  int accumulator = 0;
  for (auto _ : state) {
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(t);
    std::apply([&accumulator](auto&... args) {
        ((accumulator = args->foo(accumulator)), ...);
      }, t);
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(accumulator);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(TestVirtualFunclWithKnownType);

static void TestVirtualFunclWithKnownValuesType(benchmark::State& state) {
  auto t = makeValuesTuple();
  int accumulator = 0;
  for (auto _ : state) {
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(t);
    std::apply([&accumulator](auto&... args) {
        ((accumulator = args.foo(accumulator)), ...);
      }, t);
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(accumulator);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(TestVirtualFunclWithKnownValuesType);
```

- [clang with libstdc++ results](https://quick-bench.com/q/mNnRL0Uh4QzYKPqPdm78i4d8PDI) [image]
- [clang with libc++ results](https://quick-bench.com/q/Me_4PKJyKyUa6YGDTAufLkeo314)
- [gcc results](https://quick-bench.com/q/lE0mS8-IBRm4P7769oznF97R0oQ)[image]

In fact I'm surprised that `TestVirtualFunclWithKnownValuesType` produced the worst outcome on clang with libstdc++.

Note that gcc was able to optimize virtual calls if it can determine the type of the object (this is what I was warning about in comment under a question).

---

> My questions:
>
> 1. If virtual functions are indeed slower than regular once, how can I measure it and see for myself? What mistakes did I make in my
>    approach?

I suspect that in your code, this line:

```cpp
benchmark::DoNotOptimize(b->VirtualFoo());
```

Compiler moved fetch of address of virtual function outside testing loop. `p` doesn't change, so address of virtual function doesn't change too, so fetching it can be done before testing loop.
Adding this line can change a lot:

```cpp
benchmark::DoNotOptimize(b);
```

> 2. Why in this tests I sometimes see virtual functions being slower than regular once?

How nay times did you run your test? Are you sure you didn't reached timer limitations and you see just pure statistical fluctuations?